# dplyr row sum on selected rows

Tags: r, dplyr, rowsum

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

 d <- data.frame(
  Type= c("d", "e", "d", "e"),
  "2000"= c(1, 5, 1, 5),
  "2001" = c(2, 5 , 6, 4),
  "2002" = c(8, 9, 6, 3))
```

I would like to use rowsum and mutate to generate a new row which is the sum of 'd' and another row which is the sum of 'e' so that the data looks like this:

```
d2 <- data.frame(
Type= c("d", "e", "d", "e", "sum_of_d", "Sum_of_e"),
"2000"= c(1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 10),
"2001" = c(2, 5 , 6, 4, 8, 9),
"2002" = c(8, 9, 6, 3, 14, 12))
```

I think the code should look something like this:

```
d %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(sum_of_d = rowSums(d[1,3], na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(sum_of_e = rowSums(d[2,4], na.rm = TRUE)) -> d2
```

however this does not quite work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you need: `rowSums(.[c(1,3)], na.rm = TRUE)` and `rowSums(.[c(2,4)], na.rm = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the sum by Type across all other columns, so..

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
   group_by(Type) %>% 
   summarise_all(sum) %>% 
   mutate(Type = paste0("sum_of_", Type)) %>% 
   rbind(d, .)

      Type X2000 X2001 X2002
1        d     1     2     8
2        e     5     5     9
3        d     1     6     6
4        e     5     4     3
5 sum_of_d     2     8    14
6 sum_of_e    10     9    12
```

Comment: LOL - I just posted the exact same solution...

Comment: Yeah that's prefect, thanks - I've not used summarise_all before so that'll be really useful

Answer (score 0):

```
d %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarize_all(sum) %>% 
   mutate(Type=paste0("sum_of_",Type)) %>% 
   bind_rows(d,.)
      Type X2000 X2001 X2002
1        d     1     2     8
2        e     5     5     9
3        d     1     6     6
4        e     5     4     3
5 sum_of_d     2     8    14
6 sum_of_e    10     9    12
```